# Retrieving a contact that I called and talked to on Telegram, but accidentally deleted

Tags: contacts, calls, telegram

I talked to this person on Telegram (sent many messages, exchanged pictures), and then called them a few months ago via default Calls Android application.

Contact was deleted (call logs too), and Telegram chat / contact deleted as well.

Is there any way I could retrieve this person's telegram contact, or telephone number?

Telephone company only saves 1 month call logs (Vodafone).

Answer (score -1):

The following steps from [How can I recover deleted Telegram chats?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-recover-deleted-Telegram-chats) should work:

> Use the iKeyMonitor app to recover all the messages that you need quickly.
>
> 1. Sign up
>
> Sign up for a 3-day free account of iKeyMonitor to recover deleted
>   Telegram messages.
>
> 2. Log in to the Cloud Panel
>
> Log in to the Cloud Panel to download iKeyMonitor to the target
>   Android phone or iPhone.
>
> 3. Install iKeyMonitor
>
> Install iKeyMonitor and activate it with your license key.
>
> 4. Start Recovering
>
> Start recovering deleted Telegram messages on Cloud Panel.

Comment: How exactly does it work? How can I know it's safe?

Comment: @Tomas have you tried it?

Comment: I will, but I want to know how it works. What if it steals my credentials or something.

Comment: @Tomas it won't, if you don't want to look at other options in the linked article

Comment: "I am afraid that is not possible. Telegram is cloud based. Once you delete your chats, they are also deleted on the servers and can’t be retrieved. More so if you do it for the person with whom you are chatting in the next 48 hours." what about this comment there? why would this app work if it's true?

Comment: Based on my understanding, this app is a [monitoring and logging tool](https://ikeymonitor.com/monitor-telegram-messages.html) using keylogging and accessing current data on the Android device. While it claims [it can recover deleted messages](https://blog.ikeymonitor.com/recover-deleted-telegram-messages.html#Restore_Deleted_Telegram_Messages_with_iKeyMonitor), I think it depends on the previously logged data. I kind of doubt it'll work for messages already deleted before using this app...